# UITableViewCell shadow

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

How to add a shadow to both sides, top and bottom, of UITableViewCell?

I have tried this:

```
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

However, it only displays a shadow to the bottom of the cell.

Comment: change cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5);

Comment: already tried that, but it's not working too

Comment: For performance issues, I would not recommend to do it programmatically.

Comment: I am just adding shadow when cell is pressed

Comment: Doing it pragmatically isn't the issue @adhumi. In fact, there isn't any other way to do it. First, are your cells subclassed Olimjon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in z position of UITableViewCell. Actually, it was displaying the top shadow too, but the upper cell had bigger z position so that top shadow was under it.

I have just changed the z position of cell layer like this:

```
selectedCell.layer.zPosition = 999;
```